# Why does stability only consider, whether the system is bounded? That doesn't mean the response is smooth?

Tags: stability

Why does (BIBO) stability only consider, whether the system is bounded? That doesn't mean the response is smooth?

That is, one could have system whose values are bounded. Still it could exhibit "chaotic" behaviour through its parameters.

So what is this kind of stability/instability concept really helpful for?

Comment: In your opinion, what criterion _should_ be used to decide if a system is BIBO-stable? That the response is "smooth", whatever than means, or "non-chaotic" whatever that means? Do you even know what  BIBO is an initialism of?

Answer (score 2):

BIBO stability applies to **linear systems** with inputs and outputs.  See

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability

There is a section on linear systems with inputs.  The article is clear and restating it here is unnecessary.

Comment: for example! Among very many others, for example $y=x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Boundedness. It's usefulness is really boundedness for any input. Basically, nearly all algorithms you apply to signals break apart when there's $\infty$ in there – so, a system being bounded in output is an *extremely* helpful property.

This becomes even moreso if you consider that basically *all* other properties of your system are only meaningful if you can quantify its output.

For example, is a system that always outputs infinity "chaotic" according to you? We might never now, as there's no way to compare two infinite "values".

You can't build an average with a system that generates infinity once. There's no measure-preserving mappings here; you can't even do proper stochastic modelling.

BIBO stability is the cornerstone of analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Your question could be made more precise: smooth or chaotic, in what domain?

For discrete systems, a sufficient condition for being BIBO is that the impulse response $h[k]$ (as a discrete series) is absolutely summable  ($|\sum h[k]| < +\infty$), then its (continuous) Fourier transform $H(f)$ is defined, is bounded, and continuous.

Fourier existence for series remains, as far as I know, an open topic. However I expect, through this example, to convey the idea that a simple BIBO condition might yield some non-chaotic or non-unsmooth  behavior.

Perhaps one could provide more insights on classes of input signals. By the way, a less stringent condition is the so-called "step-response stability", yet I don't have much experience with it.